# Why can I still see my tmodloader files even though I deleted them with check integrity

Tags: terraria, mods

I tried fixing a problem with my Terraria mods by checking integrity of game files and now my mod files are "ghost files".

My original problem was when trying to log on after loading the vanilla stuff and went to loading mods (the first loading thing that appears of like 10) it didn't fill up one bit. I clicked verify integrity of files, and now I have all the tmodloader stuff but the game went back to vanilla Terraria and just simply wont use them.

I put "ghost files" because the files of tmodloader were there with nothing deleted and yet it was still vanilla Terraria. I think I might have overloaded my PC with mods (my PC hates mods and lags more with them and tmodloader isn't the best at loading mods but can do it) but I couldn't even get to the main menu and I wasn't thinking about the old uninstall and reinstall I clicked check integrity of game files but now my files are ghost files new edit also I don't know if this maters but my tmodloader is on my games>Terraria> then you see it.

Comment: turns out doing that actually deletes mods but its odd I can sill see tmodloader in terraria

Comment: I was going to delete tmodloader and get new mods but theres actually a error  not allowing me to delete them I will go on about this by searching the code(it gives you a code to look up and see how to fix)

Comment: actually I tried some thing else  I had I think a copy or some thing of tmodloader in my recycle bin first I tried to delete that then delete the other one (the in still in terraria) that didn't work but then I renamed the one in terraria allowing me to delete it (the one in terraria) this probably isn't the usaual fix but it worked so if its like my try renaming it but if that doesn't work then actually look up the code ( I did not pay attention to the code for the error I had but that realy doesn't matter)

Comment: please still leave this up because this is valueable information  and to peeps that are not mods never click check integrity of files unless you want to get rid of mods and I also could have avoided the error issue (of not allowing delete not the "ghost files"" if I hadn't copied it (I think" and if you get "ghost files " too  delete the tmodloader also im not sad because I had mest up being able to go to vanilla again (you cant get on some servers with mods) also I am starting a new series (no im not a youtuber I just said the word)